# Как реализовать проверку сразу нескольких прокси на Python

Tags: python, proxy

Хотел написать на Python программу, для генерации и проверки прокси. И если с первым у меня проблем не возникло, то с их проверкой есть вопрос. Я бы хотел сделать следующее:

Загрузить список прокси в текстовый файл
Чекер проверяет каждый прокси из списка. И сообщает, живой ли прокси.
Удаляет неживые прокси из текстового файла.
Как это реализовать? Можно хотя бы наводку.

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: Я начинающий в этом плане, Python изучаю недавно и я не могу понять, как это реализовать.